# SQLAlchemy with Pycharm 4

Tags: macos, sqlalchemy, pycharm, osx-yosemite, python-2.x

i installed PyCharm 4 on my Mac Yosemite, then installed SQLAlchemy through easy_install with console, also I have already official python 2.7.9 IDLE. I tried to import SQLAlchemy module in official IDLE and it works, but in PyCharm 4 IDE it doesn't. How can i fix this error?

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/artyom/PycharmProjects/untitled/hella.py", line 1, in  import sqlalchemy ImportError: No module named sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go into Settings -> Project Settings -> Project Interpreter.

Then press configure interpreter, and navigate to the "Paths" tab.

Press the + button in the Paths area. You can put the path to the module you'd like it to recognize.